# Theorem on the basis of a field extension $F[x]/(p(x))$ where $p(x)$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, quotient-set

I am reading through Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, and while I'm usually pretty good with my ring and field theory, this theorem is giving me some trouble.

Let $p(x)$ $\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree n over the field $F$, and let K be the field $F[x]/(p(x))$. Let $\theta =  x \mod (p(x)) \in K$. Then the elements $1,\theta,\theta^2,...\theta^{n-1}$ are a basis for $K$ as a vector space over $F$.

The proof they give makes perfect sense to me, but the term $\theta= x \mod(p(x))$ $\in K$ doesn't make sense to me. Are they saying that $\theta$ is any element of the residue class of $x$? Is it the entire residue class of $x$ over the quotient ring $F[x]/(p(x))$, which would make $\theta = x + (p(x))$?

If it is the first, then for example, in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/((x^2 +1))$, $x$ would be equal to $x\mod(x^2+1)$, but so would $x+x^2+1$. Either of these bases has to construct $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, so would there be any difference in the construction? Is that the entire point of classifying $\theta$ as a residue class? To say all elements of x mod(p(x)) construct the same field extension?

Comment: Yeah, I dislike this notation. Here I would read $\theta = x \mod (p(x)) \in K$ as meaning exactly $\theta = x + (p(x)) \in K$. Or sometimes we can say $\theta = [x] \in K$ if the equivalence relation is clear from context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the multiplicative structure on $K$ and simply look at it as a vector space over $F$.  When looked at that way, yes, the elements of $K$ (including $x$) are cosets of $(p(x))$, and it's not hard to see that the vector space operations on $K$ are well defined.  And when you reimpose the multiplicative structure and look at the elements as field elements, we're saying that $p(x)=0$ in the quotient ring, which is a field, so it makes sense that adding $p(x)$ to a representative of an equivalence class doesn't change anything.

There's an error in your question.  I think you want to say (in your last paragraph) that either base has to consruct $\Bbb Q(i)$.

Comment: You're right about $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ thank you for pointing out that error, I'll make an edit to the question, and thank you. So x is just a representative of an equivalence class, and there's ultimately no difference in which we use as long as it's equal to x mod p(x) in the quotient field?

Comment: @MajorMath  Correct.  In the quotient field, it's the difference between using $i$ or using $i+ (i^2+1)$.

Comment: Wow! That example basically instantly clarified the question, it makes sense that since the cosets are equivalent, that under the isomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$[x]/($x^2+1$) to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, any representative of the coset would reduce back to i. Thank you!